# controlling text with javascript

Tags: javascript

I wonder if anyone can help me with this please? I have this bit of HTML

```
<td class="fieldarea">
<label for="cycle1" class="radio-inline">{$pricing.monthly}</label>
</td>
```

`{$pricing.monthly}` - spits out something like this '£9.99 one year'.

I cant control what it spits out and sometimes there may be a free product which would show like this: `£0.00 one year`

Which is pretty ugly. I want to be able to control the text with this logic:

```
< If text in .radio-inline = '£0.00' replace with the text ' ' (hide it) >
```

Hopefully that kind of thing is possible?

Comment: What templating engine is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the $pricing.monthly value.

Try this logic using [`indexof`](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var emptyprice = "£0.00";
//loop thru elements with radio-inline class
var labels = document.getElementsByClassName("radio-inline");
for(var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++)
{
// Compare the price with the £0.00`
var aPosition = labels[i].textContent.indexOf(emptyprice);
// Then check if the aPosition if dosn't equal to -1...

 if (aPosition !== -1){
  // replace £0.00 year with 1 years
  var str = labels[i].textContent;
  labels[i].textContent = str.replace(emptyprice, "1")+' year';

}
}
});
```

```html
<td class="fieldarea">
<label for="cycle1" class="radio-inline">
£0.00
</label>
</td>
<hr>
<td class="fieldarea">
<label for="cycle1" class="radio-inline">
£9.99
</label>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I cant edit the code, so need it to specifically look to see if £0.00 is there and if so, hide it.

Comment: you want to hide the td !?

Comment: is this what you'r looking for, i the £0.00 automaticly hidden

Comment: I need:

 If text in label.radio-inline = '£0.00' then remove/hide it

Comment: Well, that what happend there is to label one with 9.99 and 0.00 the 0.00 is automaticly hidden

Comment: but you have two instances of the code (<td class="fieldarea">)

The only code to use is:

<td class="fieldarea">
<label for="cycle1" class="radio-inline">{$pricing.monthly}</label>
</td>

Comment: The javascript code will execute when the page load, that mean at the client side

Comment: Ive added this but it has no effect:

<script>
var emptyprice = "£0.00";


//loop thru elements with radio-inline class
var labels = document.getElementsByClassName("radio-inline");
for(var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++)
{
// Compare the price with the £0.00`
var aPosition = labels[i].textContent.indexOf(emptyprice);
// Then check if the aPosition if dosn't equal to -1...

 if (aPosition !== -1){
  labels.item(i).style.display = "none";

}
}
</script>

Comment: did you put it inside $(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ });

Comment: AH! ok yes sorry I did not complete the code properly. Ok that works in that it hides everything inside .radio-inline

However I only want to specifically hight the wording'£0.00'

Eg it might say '£0.00 1 year'

I would want the price hidden to just show '1 year'

Is that possible?

Comment: check the code, and please mark it as solved and give it an upvote. thanks

Comment: sorry but I dont want to 'replace' the text '£0.00' with '1 year' - I simply want to hide the text '£0.00' and leave any other text as it is.

It may be '£0.00 1 year' it £0.00 2 years' etc. - I just want to remove the '£0.00 bit.

Comment: AH ok fixed

  labels[i].textContent = str.replace(emptyprice, "")+' ';

Thank you very much ;P

Answer (score 0):

what framework it is? u can parse numbers at your js and do some action with html. for example if Angular js u can hide span with  directive ng-hide/ng-show/ng-if

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Thats all way above my limited knowledge Im afraid!. If I new what that all meant I would probably be able to write the code myself :)